# Install current version and update or wait until next release

Tags: upgrade, updates

I have worked with Ubuntu on the past, but for some work related reasons I had to switch to Windows some months ago. I'm ready to go back to Ubuntu now. It seems a weird time to change, so close to the next release. On one hand I'd rather not wait until 19.10 is released, as Windows is giving me some headaches. On the other hand it doesn't seem the best thing to install Ubuntu 19.04 just to upgrade the distro just two weeks from now. This situation arises some questions to me.

- What are the handicaps of upgrading a release compared to a clean installation? i.e. regarding performance, compatibility issues, driver issues, bloat files, possible lost of space...
- What are the handicaps of installing a beta release and upgrading to stable release when ready compared to a clean stable installation? How easy is it to jump from beta to stable release?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Install 18.04 LTS. This is the best choice for those who ask this type of questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no problems in upgrading (do-release-upgrade) from 19.04 to 19.10 when 19.10 is released. The upgrade process will clean out any unneeded programs and files from the old version.

When you install a beta release, there are a risk that there will be some errors, that in worse case will make your system unbootable. Normally you only see minor glitches, and they are normally fixed quickly - but the risk is there. In the beta-period, there will be much more updates than you see in a stable release.

The transition from beta to stable is just another `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` (or a click in the software updater) - like any other update.

Comment: There is much more risk in upgrading from one release to another, than installing a beta. In my opinion all non-LTS are beta quality anyway.